# UnicodeDecodeError with Python2.7, ImportError: no module named html.entities with Python 3.4

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

The problem is this: my project on hosting does not work as it should.
What we have:

- two environments with the same set of modules - one on python 2.7, another on 3.4.
- project site (link to github):
  https://github.com/Sibiryakanton/site_NL

If index.wsgi connects the path to django in 2.7, the site is displayed, but there are no css styles. Link:

http://j-star.ru/

Also, I can not give the python command manage.py migrate - it produces an error: UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can not decode byte 0xd0 in position 0: ordinal not in range (128).

If I connect django from the environment with 3.4, the migration is fine, but the error is ImportError: no module named html.entities. I understand, this is due to BeautifulSoup4 and opening py-files "pythons" of the wrong versions. Correct, if I made a mistake.

Actually, the question: what should I do?

Just in case, I attached the code **index.wsgi**:

```
import os, sys

Sys.path.append ('/ home / c / cc54094 / django / public_html / site_NL')
Sys.path.append ('/ home / c / cc54094 / virtualenv-1.11.6 / env-2 / lib / python2.7 / site-packages /')
Os.environ ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'project_nl.settings'
Import django
Django.setup ()

Import django.core.handlers.wsgi
Application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler ()
```